# Loading Angular2 app inside Ember JS application

Tags: javascript, angular, ember.js, ember-cli, angular-cli

I am having an **Angular 2** application and there is a requirement that I have to call my Angular 2 application from the **EmberJS application**. The case is when EmberJS application loads and on click of a button I want to load my Angular application in the same container do some stuff and then give back the control to EmberJS. Using Angular 2 CLI I have created a production build of my app, so I need to know how can I expose a method or a function which can be called in ember js which I can use to pass data from Angular to Ember. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This really isn't a supported/recommended architecture;  Both Angular2 and EmberJs expect to have control over the DOM to manage their data bindings, and are going to have problems with another framework making changes to the DOM without their knowledge.

Comment: Ya I know this is not a standard way of doing things, but there is an existing Ember app there is another app built using Angular 2, both these apps have some dependency on each other and my client wants to load the angular app in the ember app like the Ember app will be parent app and angular app will be the child app. And they will share some data with each other. I want to know how can I share data in between these two apps.

Comment: That's just it;  it's not that it isn't "standard", it is that these two frameworks are actively non-compatible.  It would not be possible to run both on the same page without making large changes to the internal code base of one or the other, or maybe both.

Comment: Angular has no concept of being a "child app" inside another framework

Comment: Thanks Claies for your comments, but we are in the phase of building these two apps so we can definately make code changes. So I want to know what changes are required in order to make this work.

Comment: I'm not suggesting changes to your code;  the frameworks themselves would have to be redesigned to not actively collide.  This isn't in the roadmap for either framework, so it is unlikely that you will find an answer here.

Comment: I actually created a small POC and was able to load the Angular2 app inside the Ember App. After building the angular app I took the bundle files and loaded it in the public/assets folder of Ember and created a route in Ember which basically routes to angular. Added app-root in the ember handlebar template and I was able to load the application and again pass the control back to Ember, all through routing. I am not if this will work with a enterprise application, but my POC worked.

Comment: Have you thought about loading the Angular app in an `<iframe>` from within the Ember app?

Answer (score 1):

you can import the components you have created in your angular app easily to ember once you convert them to web components.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@IMM9O/web-components-with-angular-d0205c9db08f) to create angular web-components. It will save you the effort of rewriting your code!

Another workaround could be using iframe to load the angular app inside the ember application.